# AsyncTask and ResultSet on android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, resultset

I have a problem when I use the AsyncTask, this code works fine, but when I return a ResultSet, in the mainActivity i haven't the result of the AsyncTask, and my app break. I try using a timer and a Thread.sleep and don't work

```
     blast_dbConnect task = new blast_dbConnect("asd","123",MainActivity.this);
    task.execute("Conectando",sql);
try {
        if(rs.next()==true && rs!=null){

            String passCheck;
            passCheck = rs.getString("password");
            Log.i("Se conecta",passCheck);
            tv3.setText(passCheck);


        /*catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
        /*if(passCheck.equals(password)){
            Log.i("Se conecta","Se conecta");
            return rs;
        }*/

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my synctask code
        rs is a ResultSet (I want that my synctask return a resultset. My synctask is this

```
        public class blast_dbConnect extends AsyncTask<String,String,ResultSet> {
String username;
String password;
Context c;
ProgressDialog pd;
private String ipServidorMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/cuetospalace";
private String contrasenaMySQL="636251630";
private String usuarioMySQL = "sdelcueto";


public blast_dbConnect(String user,String pass,Context context){
     username = user;
     password = pass;
     c = context;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setMessage("Conectando");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

}
@Override
protected ResultSet doInBackground(String...params) {
    boolean login = false;
    String input = params[1];
    //publishProgress(input);
    try{
         try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection conn;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/cuetospalace","sdelcueto","636251630");
        conn =  (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(ipServidorMySQL, usuarioMySQL, contrasenaMySQL);
        //Log.i("SQL",input);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //Log.i("Se conecta","Se conecta");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(input);
        /*if(rs.next()==true){


            String passCheck = rs.getString("password");

            return passCheck;
            /*if(passCheck.equals(password)){
                Log.i("Se conecta","Se conecta");
                return rs;
            }*/

        //}
        return rs;

    }
    catch(SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        //Log.i("bla",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String...params){
    //Log.i("onProgressUpdate","onProgressUpdate");
    pd.setMessage(params[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute(ResultSet rs){

    //Log.i("onPostExecute","onPostExecute");
    MainActivity.rs=rs;
    if(pd != null)
        pd.dismiss();
    //pd.cancel();


}
protected void onCancelled (){
    //Log.i("onCancelled","onCancelled");
    cancel(true);
}
```

}'
I want to he main thread wait for the AsyncTask finish, I try the get function too
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want main thread wait for asyncTask , so why not do your work in main thread?

if you want that you can run a `ProgressDialog` with `cancelable= false` in `onPreExecute()` and then in `onPostExecute()` dismis that dialog.

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("please wait...");

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         //background task
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

UPDATE:
in your code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){    
    blast_dbConnect task = new      blast_dbConnect("asd","123",MainActivity.this);
   task.execute("Conectando",sql);
 }

 public void useRS(ResultSet rs){
    this.rs = rs;
    try {
       if(rs!=null && rs.next()==true){

          String passCheck;
          passCheck = rs.getString("password");
          Log.i("Se conecta",passCheck);
          tv3.setText(passCheck);


         /*catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        */
       /*if(passCheck.equals(password)){
           Log.i("Se conecta","Se conecta");
           return rs;
       }*/

       }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

in onPostExecute():

```
onPostExecute(ResultSet rs){
   if(pd!=null)
      pd.dismis();
   useRS(rs);
}
```

Comment: It fails, in   if(rs.next()==true && rs!=null), this line code is in my main thread, is a nullPointerException

Comment: I edit my post, you can see my code there. Rs is a resultSet, I want my synctask return a resultset

Comment: can you put your Try/catch in main thread to a method and call that method in onPostExecute() ,not in main thread?

Comment: also you should write your if like this:  if(rs!=null && rs.next()==true) . first check null, so you don't get NPE.

Comment: I don't understand you sorry :-(

Comment: uffff, you save my live MHP, thx, really thx, is a easy solve, but i crazy head is like this jajaja. Ty really

Comment: happy to help. so please set answer as accepted answer :)